# iPhone app will not run due to expired beta?

Tags: iphone

I'm not in the developer program. I can run the app fine on my iPhone, and on my friends iPhone. But when I unplug his iPhone and try to run the app is says "MYAPP beta has expired".

Anyone know how to fix this without paying apple?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  Create a new user account on your Mac for your friend.  Copy the Xcode project from your account to his account.  Delete your Apple ID from that project copy.  Have him log into his new account on your Mac, and configure it using his Apple ID.  Then build the app using Xcode with his Apple ID for the personal provisioning profile, and install the app on his iPhone from his account.

Note that personal provisioning profiles might only be valid for something around one week.  For longer profile expiration times on stock iOS devices, you will need to enroll in Apple's Developer Program.